# pandas: Unable to write values to single row dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a single row dataframe(df) on which I want to insert value for every column using only the index numbers.
The dataframe df is in following form.

```
 a b c
1 0 0 0
2 0 0 0
3 0 0 0

df.iloc[[0],[1]] = predictions[:1]
```

This gives me the following warning and does not write anything to the row:

```
SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
```

However when I try using

```
pred_row.iloc[0,1] = predictions[:1]
```

It gives me error

```
ValueError: Incompatible indexer with Series
```

Is there a way to write value to single row dataframe.
Predictions is any random value that I am trying to set in a particular cell of df

Comment: What is `predictions` ? Can you add some sample?

Comment: @jezrael prediction is any random value that I am predicting and adding it to a column in df

Comment: so what is `print (type(predictions[:1]))` ?

Comment: @jezrael <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>

Comment: Can you add yout complete code, what do you try? Because is not possible set one element of DataFrame by Series - array. Maybe need `df.iloc[0, :] = predictions[:1].values` if want set first row of df by `predictions[:1]`

Comment: Also `I have a single row dataframe(df)` - and your sample is 3 row Dataframe. So it is `predictions` ? Then what is `df` ?

Comment: @jezrael I did realise my mistake. I wanted to set first element of predictions series to dataframe df cell. predictions[:1].values worked.

Answer (score 0):

For set one element of `Series` to `DataFrame` change selecting to `predictions[0]`:

```
print (df)
   a  b  c
1  0  0  0
2  0  0  0
3  0  0  0

predictions = pd.Series([1,2,3])
print (predictions)
0    1
1    2
2    3
dtype: int64

df.iloc[0, 1] = predictions[0]
#more general for set one element of Series by position
#df.iloc[0, 1] = predictions.iat[0]
print (df)
   a  b  c
1  0  1  0
2  0  0  0
3  0  0  0
```

**Details**:

```
#scalar 
print (predictions[0])
1

#one element Series
print (predictions[:1])
0    1
dtype: int64
```

---

Also working convert one element `Series` to one element array, but set by scalar is simplier:

```
df.iloc[0, 1] = predictions[:1].values
print (df)
   a  b  c
1  0  1  0
2  0  0  0
3  0  0  0

print (predictions[:1].values)
[1]
```